# Computation of Expansion Scalar in FLRW universe with curvature - help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature

Can anyone please help me with the computation of the expansion scalar $\Theta$ in an FLRW universe with curvature defined by the metric:
$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a^2(t)\left[\frac{dr^2}{1-\kappa r^2}+r^2(d\theta^2+\mbox{sin}^2 \theta d\phi^{2})\right]~?$$
I have computed it to be
$$3H+\frac{3\kappa r \dot{r}}{1-\kappa r^2}.$$
But, I do not feel much confident about my calculation. In case this is right, then what should I do with $r$ and $\dot{r}$? Can the expression be reduced further?

Comment: The expansion scalar is defined as $3H$ only. You shouldn't get an extra term unless you are using a different definition

Comment: I finally got it right with some help from Peter Donis. The expansion scalar equals 3H only in the cosmological setting. You were right in mentioning that. If we consider a different metric (other than FLRW), then of course the expansion scalar will be different. Anyways, thank you very much for your comment @MoziburUllah